# How to give a variable from another class, a value in swift?

Tags: swift4

I want to change a variable's value in class A through class B
I've done it with the code below But changing a variable's value can only be done by a function and if I use it in another function (print test)  it returns nil
What am I doing wrong???

Class A :

```
class A: ViewController {
var port : Int? = nil
var server : String? = nil


func updateServerAndport(S:String , p : Int){
    server = S
    port = p
}
func printTest{
print (server)
}
```

Class B:

```
class B: ViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var server: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var port: UITextField!
 let objA= A()
 @IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {
        objA.updateServerAndport(s = server.text!, p : port.text!)
}
}
```

Comment: How you redirect to class B ? via class A ??

Comment: I'm not sure i get your point but i just make an object's of class A in Class B and then call updateServerAndport func in class A

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question, only because I want to possibly help anyone else with this same problem in the future.just need to change the code like this:

```
 static var port : Int? = nil
 static var server : String? = nil
```

Comment: That's the worst way to share data between controllers.

Comment: that's the only way that i could find to do exactly what i want. Why this way is the worst way???

Comment: Because controllers are instances of a class. The `static` properties affect **all** instances. So if you want to use the controller in an other environment `port` and `server` are always the same. The recommended ways are protocol/delegate, callback closures and notifications.

Comment: "The static properties affect all instances. So if you want to use the controller in an other environment port and server are always the same".this is exactly what i want and in you suggest that  protocol/delegate, callback closures and notifications is better??? (I already try notification and it's don't do what i want

Answer (score 0):

Just simply do like this:

```
//Update your save function in class B with it.

@IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {

     var dictServerVal:[String: Any] = [:]
     dictServerVal["serverText"] = server.text!
     dictServerVal["portText"] = port.text!

     NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.init("YourKeyName"), object: nil, userInfo: dictServerVal)
}
```

Write bellow code in class A

```
class A: ViewController {

var port : Int? = nil
var server : String? = nil

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateServerAndport(notification:)), name: "YourKeyName", object: nil)
}

func updateServerAndport(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let dict = notification.userInfo as? [String: Any] {
        if let strServerText = dict["serverText"] as? String, let strPortText = dict["portText"] as? String {
               server = strServerText
               port = strPortText
        }
    }    
}
```